# geometry package is not working in all pages

Tags: margins, align, geometry

The `geometry` package in combination with `amsmath`'s `align` environment is not working in all pages. When many lines are within the `align` environment they get automatically shifted onto the next page and the bottom of the previous is left blank.

Comment: So what can we do for you with this kind of information?

Comment: Please suggest a solution. So that all pages look in equal (same) format.

Comment: I think you are using `align` environment from `amsmath` and that there are many lines of equations inside `align`. If they come at the bottom of the page, they won't break across the page. You have to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble (say just before `\begin{document}`. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it is working ! Thank you very much Harish

Comment: Deepesh I have added it as the answer. You may kindly upvote and accept if it has solved your problem. :-)

Comment: @DeepeshPatel: Please, when you receive helpful answers, *upvote* them (by clicking the upward pointing arrow next to the post). Also, when a post answers your question, *accept* it by clicking the tick mark next to the post. That helps other users with similar problems to quickly find helpful answers.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

I think you are using align environment from `amsmath` and that there are many lines of equations inside align. If they come at the bottom of the page, they won't break across the page. You have to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble (say just before `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks    %% Add this
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    <your equations>
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Harish ! I am using \allowdisplaybreaks command. It was working but at the places where many equations are under a curly braces, there the problem still occured. What I do in that cases.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel A list of formulas with a brace on their left can't be broken across pages.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel: Please take my code above, paste your equation where `<your equations>` is there and post it a new question. The above code is called `mwe`. That will help us to help you. :-)

Comment: which codes you are talking about ?

Comment: @DeepeshPatel: I mean put the code for offending equations inside `\begin{align` and `\end align` of  code in the above answer. Please read: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)